# What does the digit at end of flagged post title represent?

Tags: discussion, flag-history

I flagged a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688330/int-vs-guid-or-uuid-who-fast) for being opinion-based today and I noticed something odd. There was a tiny digit next to the title in my Flagged posts list as shown in the following image:

[image]

I have never seen it before. What does this `1` represent? I tried googling about it but must be searching the wrong thing because I found nothing.

My guesses are:

1. *It is representing that one other user has flagged this post for being opinion-based.*
2. *It is representing that one mod has found it helpful (Which I believe is unlikely).*

What does it actually represent?

Comment: The number of answers?

Comment: @vaultah Yes that's it! thank you so much. I just scrolled down In the history list and noticed some other posts with this count badge. they had exactly the same number of answers as the badge stated. If you'll be so Kind to post it as the answer, I would be able to mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: You would've seen it if you hovered the cursor over it and read the tooltip.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This appears to be the total number of answers on the linked page (excluding deleted answers), if any.

> [image: screenshot with tooltip]

It won't be shown if the link points to an answer.